# Oops! Something Bad Happened! loading user profiles on meta sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, 500-server-error

When loading a user profile on *any* site meta, e.g. meta.sf, meta.su, or meta.so, a 500 Internal Server Error is returned.

(This image was submitted to me by a site user.)

[image: Oops! Something Bad Happened!]

This is only happening on *meta* sites, but it is all over the network.

Comment: Saw the same, but it looks like it's fixed already.

Comment: No repro on Writers and Mi Yodeya.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Yep, it seems to be fixed now.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

An attempt at fixing an issue with reputation graphs has not taken into account that meta sites don't have reputation.

Sorry about that!

I can take credit for breaking it, but not for fixing it - thanks Nick Craver!

Comment: So why did you steal 75 repz (and still counting) from him?! ;-)

Comment: I thought it was repz for breaking things?

Comment: Ah, but there's more repz in sayin' sorry. ;)

Comment: @Shadow ...make that 145 :P

Comment: Well actually Oded stole 185+ rep...